# Connecting to a database on another machine through Java application

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

If a java desktop application from a client machine needs to connect to a database on an external central server (on another machine), kind of like a php script that can connect from a browser on the client machine to a database, how would that be accomplished? I know that you can use JDBC, but wouldn't the person who's running the desktop application need mysql connector/j driver installed on his/her computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course: if an application is using JDBC to connect to a DB they'll need the appropriate JDBC driver.

Most applications already have a set of library dependencies; it would just be another one.

Comment: So if I were to package this application so that users can download it and use it, how would I include the jdbc library in the package?

Comment: Depends on how you're packaging/distributing it. If it's a tar/zip file with an execution script, put it in the existing `lib` directory with the rest. Or use something like jarjar/onejar to create an all-in-one jar file. Or through [jnlp resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources) (but I don't know how any of that works).

Comment: @user791345, A JDBC driver is just another Java class.  You should be able to add the driver jar exactly the same way you would add any other dependencies.

Comment: @MikeDeck Hi mike, I almost got the same problem. I've installed Oracle 12c (desktop class) on my machine, and I can use it via sql developer on the same machine. Now how can I use the same database from another machine (for java application) in the LAN?
I tried using the jdbc thin driver as follows: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.11.69:1521:orcl`  where 10.0.11.69 is my ip address where Oracle is installed.
Do i need to install any server where oracle is installed(10.0.11.69) to connect to my db from another machine?

Comment: @abc123 ... Besides that this comment thread is the years old, if you have a question, post a question. You need an open port as well.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you bundle the appropriate JDBC driver (usually a jar) with the application and make sure it's on the runtime classpath everything should work.  There is no "installation" of the driver separate from having the appropriate classes on the application's classpath.